# sequelize dynamic query params

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm sending query params as JSON format in `req.query.p` from my front-end MVC framework  , the point is that this could be a dynamic key and value, for example:

```
req.query.p = {nombre : 'juan'}
```

or

```
req.query.p = {pais : 'chile'}
```

So I need the key, and the value to put them in the where statement, something like this

```
exports.select = function(req, res){
    console.log('=> GET | Obtener peliculas'.bold.get);
        db.Pelicula
            .findAndCountAll({
                limit : req.query.limit,
                offset : req.query.offset,
                where : req.query.p ? [req.query.p.KEY + " = ?", req.query.p.VAL] : null
            })
            .success(function(resp){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.rows, null, 4).bold.get);
                res.json({peliculas : resp.rows, meta : { total : resp.count}});
            });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The where parameter can be an object, so you can just pass `where: req.query.p`

Comment: Thanks you! it works :P. Btw what about if i want to pass more than one args to my query? Which is the right way to handle this?

Comment: `where: { arg1: something, arg2: somethingelse }` - plain old javascript objects

Comment: What's the operation there? "...where arg1 = something AND/OR? arg2 = somethingelse"

Comment: Default is AND. If you want OR, use `where: sequelize.or({ arg1: something }, { arg2: somethingelse })`. I'd suggest to take a look at the guides on http://sequelizejs.com/ and the API docs at http://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/API-Reference

Answer (score 0):

Usually I put the entire object, so if it comes empty, it will work normally as if there is no conditional WHERE.
You don't need to add {} in the where, because the object that comes from req.query already has it.

```
const filter = req.query;
example= await ModelExample.findAndCountAll({
               where:
                filter
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 and with usage of the dynamic properties I'll do it like this

```
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

const from = new Date()
// const to = new Date().setMinutes(40)
const to = null

let where = {
    timestamp: {
        [Op.or]: {}
    }
}

if (from) {
    where.timestamp[Op.or][Op.gte] = new Date(from)
}
if (to) {
    where.timestamp[Op.or][Op.lte] = new Date(to)
}
console.log(where);

Model.find({ where })
```